# Using rows and column from bootstrap for mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a site and using bootstrap 3.3.5. The only problem I am having at the moment is the row/column structure I have is not displaying correctly on mobile.

Here is the link to the project: https://foreverfightermovie.herokuapp.com/#/home

It looks fine so far on a computer browser, but on mobile the ribbons are stacked onto of the middle panel section. Here is the html I am using:

```
 <div class="jumbotron">
<h3 class="text-right" style="margin-right: 100px"> Production status: <b>Pre-Production</b> </h3>
 <h1 class="text-center">The official site of <h1>
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3">
<img src="/images/breast-cancer-ribbon.png" width="200" height="400" style="margin-left: 30px"/>
 </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="panel-body text-center px-font" style="background-color: pink">
    <br><b><FONT FACE="Lucida Console">FOREVER<br>FIGHTER</FONT></b><br><br>
    <h3><i>"In life you can fight forever, but you can't live forever. One is a choice and the other is a guarantee"</i><h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
    <img src="/images/breast-cancer-ribbon.png" width="200" height="400"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
   <br>
       <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center" style="color: #2BDE73">
    <img src="/images/kickstarter-logo.png" width="30" height="30"/>
    Click for Donation Pledges</a></p>
 </div>
```

Also: Here is the css I am using:

```
.tab { margin-left: 20px;
        margin-right: 20px; }

.imagetab { margin-left: 40px;
            margin-right: 40px;}

.para {
    text-indent: 40px;
}

.jumbotron {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
}

html {font-size: 90%;}

div.px-font {
  font-size: 110px;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: What would you like the outcome to be - do you want the ribbons to disappear or move to a specific location or what?

Comment: @Alex Is it possible to just get it to shrink, but stay intact? Keeps the ribbons on right/left of the panel and is static so they don't move.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap's strength is stacking, but you can override whatever you'd like in your custom CSS. For what you'd like to do I'd use a **media query** with Bootstrap's built-in breakpoints. Here's a simple example:

```
@media (max-width: @screen-sm-min) {
    /* This is the row containing your main panel and two ribbon divs. */
    .main-row { 
        position: relative; 
    }
    /* Add this to each of your ribbons. The ".left" & ".right" are self-explanatory. */
    .ribbon { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
    }
    .ribbon.left { left: 0px; }
    .ribbon.right { right: 0px; }

    /* Resize your images here to fit as you'd like them. */
    .ribbon img {
        height: 100px;
        width: 50px; 
    }
}
```

You can find some more info on the queries Bootstrap offers here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries

Comment: I am still getting used to HTML/CSS so would I add these classes onto my ribbon image tags or something?

Comment: Yep. You'd add that whole block to your CSS, then add the classes `ribbon` and `left` to your left ribbon div, `ribbon` and `right` to your right ribbon div, and `main-row` to your containing row element. You might wanna adjust the center column as well, but that's just a matter of font-size and personal taste. :)

Comment: `@media` queries like that restrict these actions to certain sizes. In this case, we're saying "apply these CSS rules only while our screen width is less than 768 pixels". They're what you want to look into as you consider sizing issues between full-screen and mobile views.

Comment: For example - If you go to yahoo.com and horizontally flatten your browser the page stays intact and just lets you scroll, but keeps it size. That is what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you don't want the page to scale from dekstop to mobile, you don't want Bootstrap. The Bootstrap grid is specifically designed to flow (move/stack) and change to respond to different size screens. You may be better using a different grid, or just writing your own CSS with `div` tags and percentage widths instead of using Bootstrap. You can find some nice tips on easy custom grid layouts here: https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/